# Why can't I use a set as the output collection of transform operation on a vector?

Tags: c++

When I use transform on a set and use a vector to store the output, it works fine. But it doesn't seem to work the other way around.

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int multiply(int a) {
    return a * 2;
}
void print(int i) {
    cout << i << " ";
}
int main() {
    int mynumbers[] = { 3,9,2,4,1 };
    vector<int> v1(mynumbers, mynumbers + 5);
    set<int> s1(mynumbers, mynumbers + 5);
    transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), s1.begin(), multiply);
    for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), print);
    cout << endl;
    for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), print);
}
```

Comment: The elements of a `set` are immutable.

Comment: There are special iterators (from the STL) that insert into another container, maybe those are what you're looking for. In any case, what are you trying to achieve? That said, "doesn't work" is not a description of anything, just a possibly flawed interpretation. Make sure to include the actual error in your question, so (hint!) it can be searched for as well. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Thank you. Btw, what I meant with it not working was it wouldn't compile. I'll try to do better at asking next time. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390905/why-cant-i-use-a-set-as-the-output-collection-of-transform-operation-on-a-vecto#comment126187694_71390905) pointed out:

> The elements of a `set` are immutable.

Thus, existing elements cannot be overwritten.

However, it can be done with e.g. a [std::insert_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream> 
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
   std::set<int> s;
   std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(),
     std::insert_iterator<std::set<int>>(s, s.begin()),
     [](int x) { return x * 2; });
   for (int x : s) std::cout << ' ' << x;
}
```

Output:

```
 2 4 6 8 10
```

[Live demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b884679f2a62ea5)

Answer (score 2):

As @JeJo already mentioned, std::inserter can be used.
Just pasting here the code with it.

```
set<int> s1;
transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), inserter(s1, s1.begin()), multiply);
```

For the testing purpose, it does not matter, although it is not good to initialize the set s1 with vector v1 values, because transform adds/overwrites entries in the target container, and in your code the new values are getting mixed with old values (e.g. 4,9)